# How do I remove AfterMap from Automapper Profiles

Tags: .net, automapper, structuremap3, xunit2

I have a profile class where I am using AfterMap() method. My profile class has two constructor dependencies. Problem is that while I am unit testing I am mocking these dependencies but also I require the actual objects when I am doing integration testing. Since im using xUnit2, everything runs in parallel, so I have no control. So that is why I want to remove all the code from aftermap. Can someone tell me the approach for this ?
I am using structuremap as my IOC container.

Comment: The idea is to use resolvers, such as MapFrom or ResolveUsing, for the properties you set in AfterMap.

Comment: could you give an example ? so i can get a better context